# we are getting an error as "this item is not cached"

Tags: artifactory

We are facing an issue with artifactori, refer to the Attached screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDf1.png)

we are facing a few issues in the remote repository xyz, We are able to see the location of it in the artifactory however on going to the location we are getting a 'This item is not cached error'. So the build is failing for our observability libraries. please let us know how we can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you see is from the virtual/remote repository and the item is not cached is the actual answer. The item is available in the remote source but not available in the Artifactory's cache. To overcome the issue, simply download the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to the "Metadata Retrieval Cache Period (Sec)". For us this was set to 2h in Administration->Repositories->Remote->YourRepo->Advanced and it prevents metadata updates within this timeout. This means, if you have rapid changes, you either have such a delay, or you change the config. We set it to "0" (no caching) and have not had this issue since then.